# Is there an accepted strategy when tackling proofs involving inequalities?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I am new to mathematical proofs, and I am not quite sure how to tackle problems of that nature.

> Here is the problem:

Prove that if $b≥-1$, $b≠0$, then $\frac{4b^2+b+1}{4|b|} ≥ \sqrt{b+1}$

I tried to rearrange the inequality on the right like so,

 $\frac{4b^2+b+1-4|b|\sqrt{b+1}}{4|b|} ≥ 0$ 

but this didn't really help me much. I am aware that I need to use the fact
that $b≥-1$ to proceed further, however, I don't know when it should come into play.

I am also not exactly sure if I always need to start working with the latter part ($\frac{4b^2+b+1}{4|b|} ≥ \sqrt{b+1}$) when dealing with proofs of this kind?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hint: $x^2+y^2\geq 2|xy|$. Do you see why this is true?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I’m sorry but due to my level of exposure to proofs involving inequalities I can’t seem to understand how can this be used in the proof? Would you please be able to explain it in further detail, if possible of course? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, there is no method that will solve any inequality. Inequalities need to be tackled case by case, although we can simplify particular forms given prior experience and knowledge. General mathematical intuition and perserverance will go a long way toward unfamiliar forms.

A specific strategy is to change your variables so the condition is something nice. This usually makes the problem much easier to read and digest. Here it doesn't change too much but it's a good general strategy to keep in mind, so I will demonstrate it anyways.

Let $b = c-1$. This means if $b \ge -1$, then $c \ge 0$. Now we can rewrite the inequality as:

$$
\frac{4(c-1)^2+c}{4|c-1|} \ge \sqrt{c}
$$

Next, notice that there is a $|c-1|$ in the denominator and a $(c-1)^2$ in the numerator. This is very good because it will be very easy to reduce.

$$
\frac{4(c-1)^2}{4|c-1|} + \frac{c}{4|c-1|} \ge \sqrt{c} \\
|c-1| + \frac{c}{4|c-1|} \ge \sqrt{c}
$$

Now multiply out the denominator:

$$
4(c-1)^2 + c \ge 4|c-1|\sqrt{c} \\
4(c-1)^2 - 4|c-1|\sqrt{c} + c \ge 0
$$

Setting $0$ on one side is very useful here because we know that $a^2 \ge 0$ for all real $a$. We can try to see if the left side is a perfect square:

$$\left(2|c-1| - \sqrt{c} \right)^2 \ge 0$$

It is in fact a perfect square! This means that as long as the expression in parentheses is real, we have a solution. The only way in which this works is if $\sqrt{c}$ is positive, or in other words, $c \ge 0$. We remove the $c = 1$ singularity and we are done!

EDIT: @pidgeon's comment is excellent, because it takes an inequality that is true for an entire domain and applies it directly. You can take that inequality and immediately apply it to a problem if you can find the clever substitutions. This will be much faster than my more brute force approach, but it is the method I use when I don't have a better one.

Another really great inequality to always keep on hand is the AM-GM-HM inequality, which simply states that for any set of positive numbers, the arithmetic mean is at least the geometric mean, which is at least the harmonic mean.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am just a little unsure how the inequality @pidgeon had included in his comment helps and how it can be applied to this proof. Is it an application of AM-GM?

Comment: How it's applied: multiply the denominator to both sides, then do the substitution $x = 2|b|$, $y = \sqrt{b+1}$. This *can* be related to AM-GM sorta (though much easier to prove by simple algebra). There is an extension called RMS-AM-GM-HM, where RMS is the "root mean square". Set RMS $\ge$ GM in the $2$ element set case, and you have pidgeon's formula.

Comment: That was crystal clear! I can’t thank you enough, thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify though, we had to choose $2|b|$ just because we recognized that we can use the inequality that @pidgeon had included in his comment to help us prove this problem? And since we used this format, the proof is now complete?

Comment: Technically, you still have to prove the inequality or accept it is true.

Answer (score 3):

Also, since both sides are nonegative, you can square it and get (recall $|x|^2 =x^2$)

$$(4b^2+b+1)^2\geq 16b^2(b+1)$$

which is the same as $$ 16b^4+b^2+1+8b^3+8b^2+2b\geq 16b^3+16b^2$$

or  $$ 16b^4+b^2+1-8b^3-8b^2+2b\geq 0$$

or $$(-4b^2+b+1)^2\geq 0$$ which is true.

Comment: I do! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM
$$\frac{4b^2+b+1}{4|b|}=|b|+\frac{b+1}{4|b|}\geq2\sqrt{|b|\cdot\frac{b+1}{4|b|}}=\sqrt{b+1}.$$

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand how you got the following. Could you perhaps walk me through the process, if possible? I'm not quite sure I understand how AM-GM can be applied when proving inequalities. Thank you!

Comment: Did you let $x = |b|$, and $y = \frac{b + 1}{4|b|}$ where $\frac{x + y}{2} \geq \sqrt{x * y}$, and then reduced it? If that's the case, didn't you start with what you actually wanted to prove? Therefore, it should be written backwards to serve as a formal mathematical proof?

Comment: Your understanding of the first question is correct. AM-GM states that $\frac{x+y}{2} \ge \sqrt{xy}$ for any real values $x$ and $y$. As long as you plug in real expressions into $x$ and $y$, it will always be true. We assume that we already understand the AM-GM inequality to be true, and then show that it implies your inequality must also hold as a consequence.

Comment: @Flavio Esposito Yes, of course! For positives $x$ and $y$. Thank you, dear  Zhuli

Comment: @Zhuli I see! So, to get the $x$ and $y$ values ($x=|b|$, and $y=\frac{b+1}{4|b|}$) every time we would like to prove a specific inequality holds, are we supposed to just brute force the right combination based on the given inequality, or is there actually an accepted way of finding a possible indication of what those values should be? I feel like that is the part I don't quite understand. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: That's just experience and intuition that comes with practice. There's no set rule or method.