# Can every inequality be proved using the AM-GM inequality?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I recently started learning about the AM-GM inequality and wanted to understand how to utilize it to prove different inequalities, and I was questioning if every inequality can be proved using that method?

I was also wondering how one can find the values of $x$ and $y$ (that are later substitued into $\frac{x+y}{2}≥\sqrt{x∗y}$ to prove the given inequality) to make use of the AM-GM? As an example, in a question that I have asked before: 
Prove that if $b≥-1$, $b≠0$, then $\frac{4b^2+b+1}{4|b|} ≥ \sqrt{b+1}$ 
A kind enough user, @Michael Rozenberg gave me an answer of how this can be solved using the AM-GM, however, I wasn't sure how did he know to let $x=|b|$, and $y=\frac{b+1}{4|b|}$, where $\frac{x+y}{2}≥\sqrt{x∗y}$ in order to nicely get the answer:$$\frac{4b^2+b+1}{4|b|}=|b|+\frac{b+1}{4|b|}\geq2\sqrt{|b|\cdot\frac{b+1}{4|b|}}=\sqrt{b+1}$$

Also, I am not quite sure how the AM-GM can applied to this question?
[image]

I managed to prove it without using AM-GM like so:

 $$\frac{4}{(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b})^2} \leq ab$$
$$ab(\frac{a+b}{ab})^2-4 \ge 0$$
$$\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2-4ab}{ab} \ge 0$$
$$\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab} \ge 0$$However, I am not sure how to use AM-GM to prove it, and how to find the neccessary values of $x$ and $y$ to do so.

I apologize for the long post. 
 **Any bit of help would be immensely appreciated!**

Comment: Why would you think that *every* inequality can be proven by AM-GM?

Comment: I thought that since we begin with something that is always true (the AM-GM inequality), given we find the right numbers that make it work ($x$ and $y$), we can always prove it. However, I am not completely sure that is correct. It's merely a thought.

Comment: That's not really right. The statement $1=1$ is also "always true", but just because of that it doesn't mean that only using this statement would allow us to prove anything we wanted. AM-GM is a theorem and using it is a technique, if you will, but there's no reason to expect it to be a universal one.

Comment: That's interesting! I wasn't really aware, thanks! So, does it mean that only if the circumstances are right, AM-GM can be used? Which suggests that on some occasions it is basically impossible?

Comment: You inequality is equivalent to $1/\sqrt{ab}\leq(1/a+1/b)/2$. Can you see it now?

Comment: @Robert Wolfe It looks more similar to the structure of the AM-GM inequality, but I am not exactly sure how to find the values of $x$ and $y$ that will allow me to prove this inequality. I thought about changing the RHS to $\frac{a}{2ab}+ \frac{b}{2ab}$, and let $x= \frac{a}{2ab}$ and $y = \frac{b}{2ab}$, but this doesn't really help.

Comment: See also HM-GM inequality @FlavioEsposito

Comment: @Robert Wolfe Yes, I see it now! I let my let $x= \frac{a}{2ab}$ and $y = \frac{b}{2ab}$, which actually worked when I subbed it into the AM-GM inequality $\frac{x+y}{2} \ge \sqrt{x*y}$. So, should choosing the $x$ and $y$ be based on my intuition?

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495663/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, AM-GM is merely one result, and manipulating an inequality into a certain form required to use AM-GM is just one technique. There's no reason to expect that this is technique will be universal and can enable us to prove any inequality.

With that said, as Robert Wolfe hinted in the comments your particular inequality does have a solution using AM-GM. Taking the reciprocal of both sides and multiplying throughout by $2$, we get
$$\frac1a+\frac1b\geq\frac{2}{\sqrt{ab}}$$
This is, of course, equivalent to AM-GM with $x=1/a,y=1/b$ so that $x+y\geq2\sqrt{xy}$ (note that we've implicitly used the fact that $a,b>0$).

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed that letting my $x= \frac{a}{2ab}$ and $y = \frac{b}{2ab}$ also worked. However, I just wanted to ask if you multiplied by $2$ because you recognized that by doing so, you could make use of the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: @FlavioEsposito It doesn't matter, of course. The two forms of AM-GM $x+y\geq2\sqrt{xy}$ and $\frac{x+y}{2}\geq\sqrt{xy}$ are equivalent. (Note that your substitutions are just $x=1/(2b)$ and $y=1/(2a)$ since the terms on the numerator and denominator cancel, so what you have is equivalent to mine with a constant factor.)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. So just to clarify, to try and make use of the AM-GM inequality we basically need to intuitively determine the values of $x$ and $y$ so they will work by playing with the information we're given?

Comment: @FlavioEsposito I wouldn't say "intuitively" since there can be a lot of tedious manipulation involved, but essentially, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The left hand side is the harmonic mean of $a$ and $b$, which is less than or equal to the geometric mean. If you wanted to use AM-GM, note that you may construct a new circle whose radius is the geometric mean and altitude is the harmonic mean.

[image]

Comment: That's an awesome visualization piece, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Also note that
AM-GM for 2 variables
can be proved without squaring
by writing
$\dfrac{x+y}{2}
\ge \sqrt{xy}
$
as
$\dfrac{x+y-2\sqrt{xy}}{2}
\ge 0
$
or
$\dfrac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2}{2}
\ge 0
$.

Similarly,
$\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b\geq\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{ab}}
$
is the same as
$(\dfrac1{\sqrt{a}}-\dfrac1{\sqrt{b}})^2
\ge 0
$.
No squaring or reciprocating.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. It seems that it all comes down to recognizing the right manipulation that is required to be made. Thanks a bunch!